# Are questions about the history and interpretation of other people's paintings off-topic here?

Tags: support, faq

I wanted to ask something about a theme that appears in a painting by the French artist James Tissot, so I thought it would be on-topic here. But it wouldn't be, right, because this is only for questions about making art and craft works?

I'm asking because I couldn't find definitive guidance in the help file.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, we are a site for applied art.

Art history and art interpretation are out of scope here.