# Is asking about an artwork off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

My sister's boyfriend painted this picture. I am not familiar with art and the only explanation I got is that it paints the light. I wanted to know more about the picture, but I don't know if it would be off-topic.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are questions about the history and interpretation of other people's paintings off-topic here?](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/are-questions-about-the-history-and-interpretation-of-other-peoples-paintings-o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you want to ask.

If you’re curious **about what the technique may be, or the color scheme,** these are things that would be helpful for someone needing to know the physical traits or skills needed to make another piece using those techniques. So, **those types of questions would probably be on topic**.

If you were going to ask **about interpreting the image, then that would not be on topic**. Although many of us love art and enjoy thinking about those things, this site is not geared towards that because it’s more discussion- and opinion-based questioning.

Comment: So, asking the question the OP asks about on the main page, it would receive comments asking to give it focus, or eventually be voted off-topic. In the state the question currently is in, it is off-topic (also based on "wanting to know more" being too broad).

Comment: @Joachim There's not really any question presented in the OP's post, so it really just depends on what the ask. The picture itself isn't off topic, but asking about stuff like who painted it would be. Whereas asking about the technique used to produce the blue squares would be on topic.